# Inverting mouse X-axis on KDE Wayland

Tags: linux, kde

I'm trying to build a makeshift trackball and one thing I'm missing is the ability to invert the mouse X-axis. I've found how to do it with `xinput` but that doesn't work for wayland. How do I do that? Using KDE wayland on Arch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.